# Slow query count with MySQL 8 where table has JSON columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Note, I think I'm encountering this bug which was marked as "Can't replicate": https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97709

That said, I'm interested if anyone has a workaround to query performance that seems to affect tables that have JSON columns. This table has roughly 45 million rows within it.

```
CREATE TABLE `loop` (
  `post_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `partner_id` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `market_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resources` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `template_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `likes` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscribers` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_event_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `_version` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`,`post_id`),
  KEY `idx_loop_prod_timestamps` (`partner_id`,`type_id`,`created`,`deleted`,`updated`),
  KEY `idx_loop_prod` (`created` DESC,`partner_id`,`type_id`,`market_id`,`user_id`,`deleted`,`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

A query that looks as follows returns in less than 80ms:

```
SELECT 
    type_id, post_id
FROM
    the_loop.loop 
WHERE
    (partner_id = 'VMF'
        AND type_id IN ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347' , 'PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba',
        'PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301',
        'PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9',
        'PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb',
        'PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')
        AND created BETWEEN '2021-02-09 00:00:00'
        AND created < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999'
        AND deleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

A count of this same query takes over a minute to return (9 million ish rows):

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM
    the_loop.loop 
WHERE
    (partner_id = 'VMF'
        AND type_id IN ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347' , 'PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba',
        'PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301',
        'PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9',
        'PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb',
        'PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')
        AND created BETWEEN '2021-02-09 00:00:00'
        AND created < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999'
        AND deleted IS NULL)
```

When using MySQL 5.7 with the same table structure, same data and same index the query returns within 3ish seconds.

*EDIT 1:*

Here is the explain statement for the above query:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "4672714.02"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "loop",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "PRIMARY",
        "idx_loop_prod_timestamps",
        "idx_loop_prod",
        "idx_loop_prod_type_id_partner_id_created_deleted"
      ],
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "type_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "502",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 23298882,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 7,
      "filtered": "0.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "4672713.29",
        "eval_cost": "0.72",
        "prefix_cost": "4672714.02",
        "data_read_per_join": "24K"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "type_id",
        "partner_id",
        "created",
        "deleted"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`the_loop`.`loop`.`partner_id` = 'VMF') and (`the_loop`.`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`the_loop`.`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `the_loop`.`loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`the_loop`.`loop`.`deleted` is null))"
    }
  }
}
```

Based upon the above explain I just created a new index:

```
ALTER TABLE `the_loop`.`loop` 
ADD INDEX `idx_loop_prod_type_id_partner_id_created_deleted` (`type_id` ASC, `partner_id` ASC, `created` ASC, `deleted` ASC) VISIBLE;
```

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here as the new index doesn't seem to affect performance if when using use/force index hints.

*EDIT 2:*

Here is the optimizer trace for the above count query. At this point I'm mostly thinking the linked oracle bug report has some validity to it.

```
SELECTcount(*)FROMthe_loop.loopWHERE(partner_id='VMF'ANDtype_idIN('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347',
'PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba',
'PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301',
'PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9',
'PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb',
'PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')ANDcreatedBETWEEN'2021-02-09 00:00:00'ANDcreated<'2021-08-08 23:59:59.999'ANDdeletedISNULL)LIMIT0,
1000,
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "join_preparation": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [
          {
            "IN_uses_bisection": true
          },
          {
            "expanded_query": "/* select#1 */ select count(0) AS `count(*)` from `loop` where ((`loop`.`partner_id` = 'VMF') and (`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null)) limit 0,1000"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "join_optimization": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [
          {
            "condition_processing": {
              "condition": "WHERE",
              "original_condition": "((`loop`.`partner_id` = 'VMF') and (`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null))",
              "steps": [
                {
                  "transformation": "equality_propagation",
                  "resulting_condition": "((`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null) and multiple equal('VMF', `loop`.`partner_id`))"
                },
                {
                  "transformation": "constant_propagation",
                  "resulting_condition": "((`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null) and multiple equal('VMF', `loop`.`partner_id`))"
                },
                {
                  "transformation": "trivial_condition_removal",
                  "resulting_condition": "((`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null) and multiple equal('VMF', `loop`.`partner_id`))"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "substitute_generated_columns": {

            }
          },
          {
            "table_dependencies": [
              {
                "table": "`loop`",
                "row_may_be_null": false,
                "map_bit": 0,
                "depends_on_map_bits": [

                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "ref_optimizer_key_uses": [
              {
                "table": "`loop`",
                "field": "partner_id",
                "equals": "'VMF'",
                "null_rejecting": false
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "rows_estimation": [
              {
                "table": "`loop`",
                "range_analysis": {
                  "table_scan": {
                    "rows": 25495539,
                    "cost": 8.92e6
                  },
                  "potential_range_indexes": [
                    {
                      "index": "PRIMARY",
                      "usable": true,
                      "key_parts": [
                        "type_id",
                        "post_id"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_loop_prod_timestamps",
                      "usable": true,
                      "key_parts": [
                        "partner_id",
                        "type_id",
                        "created",
                        "deleted",
                        "updated",
                        "post_id"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_loop_prod",
                      "usable": true,
                      "key_parts": [
                        "created",
                        "partner_id",
                        "type_id",
                        "market_id",
                        "user_id",
                        "deleted",
                        "post_id"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "index": "idx_loop_prod_type_id_partner_id_created_deleted",
                      "usable": true,
                      "key_parts": [
                        "type_id",
                        "partner_id",
                        "created",
                        "deleted",
                        "post_id"
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "best_covering_index_scan": {
                    "index": "idx_loop_prod_type_id_partner_id_created_deleted",
                    "cost": 8.91e6,
                    "chosen": true
                  },
                  "setup_range_conditions": [

                  ],
                  "group_index_range": {
                    "chosen": false,
                    "cause": "not_group_by_or_distinct"
                  },
                  "skip_scan_range": {
                    "potential_skip_scan_indexes": [
                      {
                        "index": "PRIMARY",
                        "usable": false,
                        "cause": "query_references_nonkey_column"
                      },
                      {
                        "index": "idx_loop_prod_timestamps",
                        "tree_travel_cost": 1.25,
                        "num_groups": 7046448,
                        "rows": 17933224,
                        "cost": 2.47e7
                      },
                      {
                        "index": "idx_loop_prod",
                        "tree_travel_cost": 1.25,
                        "num_groups": 6972159,
                        "rows": 25495540,
                        "cost": 2.98e7
                      },
                      {
                        "index": "idx_loop_prod_type_id_partner_id_created_deleted",
                        "tree_travel_cost": 1.25,
                        "num_groups": 7040252,
                        "rows": 17309876,
                        "cost": 2.45e7
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "best_skip_scan_summary": {
                    "type": "skip_scan",
                    "index": "idx_loop_prod_type_id_partner_id_created_deleted",
                    "key_parts_used_for_access": [
                      "type_id",
                      "partner_id",
                      "created",
                      "deleted"
                    ],
                    "prefix ranges": [
                      "PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb <= type_id <= PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                      "PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347 <= type_id <= PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                      "PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9 <= type_id <= PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                      "PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9 <= type_id <= PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                      "PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba <= type_id <= PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                      "PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301 <= type_id <= PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF"
                    ],
                    "range": [
                      "NULL <= deleted <= NULL"
                    ],
                    "chosen": false,
                    "cause": "cost"
                  },
                  "analyzing_range_alternatives": {
                    "range_scan_alternatives": [
                      {
                        "index": "PRIMARY",
                        "ranges": [
                          "PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb <= type_id <= PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb",
                          "PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347 <= type_id <= PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347",
                          "PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9 <= type_id <= PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9",
                          "PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9 <= type_id <= PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9",
                          "PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba <= type_id <= PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba",
                          "PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301 <= type_id <= PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301"
                        ],
                        "index_dives_for_eq_ranges": true,
                        "rowid_ordered": true,
                        "using_mrr": false,
                        "index_only": false,
                        "rows": 23325020,
                        "cost": 2.35e6,
                        "chosen": true
                      },
                      {
                        "index": "idx_loop_prod_timestamps",
                        "ranges": [
                          "VMF <= partner_id <= VMF AND PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb <= type_id <= PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb",
                          "VMF <= partner_id <= VMF AND PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347 <= type_id <= PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347",
                          "VMF <= partner_id <= VMF AND PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9 <= type_id <= PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9",
                          "VMF <= partner_id <= VMF AND PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9 <= type_id <= PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9",
                          "VMF <= partner_id <= VMF AND PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba <= type_id <= PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba",
                          "VMF <= partner_id <= VMF AND PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301 <= type_id <= PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301"
                        ],
                        "index_dives_for_eq_ranges": true,
                        "rowid_ordered": false,
                        "using_mrr": false,
                        "index_only": true,
                        "rows": 17933225,
                        "cost": 6.22e6,
                        "chosen": false,
                        "cause": "cost"
                      },
                      {
                        "index": "idx_loop_prod",
                        "chosen": false,
                        "cause": "no_valid_range_for_this_index"
                      },
                      {
                        "index": "idx_loop_prod_type_id_partner_id_created_deleted",
                        "ranges": [
                          "PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb <= type_id <= PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                          "PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347 <= type_id <= PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                          "PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9 <= type_id <= PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                          "PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9 <= type_id <= PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                          "PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba <= type_id <= PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF",
                          "PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301 <= type_id <= PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301 AND VMF <= partner_id <= VMF"
                        ],
                        "index_dives_for_eq_ranges": true,
                        "rowid_ordered": false,
                        "using_mrr": false,
                        "index_only": true,
                        "rows": 17309875,
                        "cost": 6.05e6,
                        "chosen": false,
                        "cause": "cost"
                      }
                    ],
                    "analyzing_roworder_intersect": {
                      "usable": false,
                      "cause": "too_few_roworder_scans"
                    }
                  },
                  "chosen_range_access_summary": {
                    "range_access_plan": {
                      "type": "range_scan",
                      "index": "PRIMARY",
                      "rows": 23325020,
                      "ranges": [
                        "PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb <= type_id <= PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb",
                        "PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347 <= type_id <= PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347",
                        "PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9 <= type_id <= PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9",
                        "PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9 <= type_id <= PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9",
                        "PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba <= type_id <= PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba",
                        "PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301 <= type_id <= PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301"
                      ]
                    },
                    "rows_for_plan": 23325020,
                    "cost_for_plan": 2.35e6,
                    "chosen": true
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "considered_execution_plans": [
              {
                "plan_prefix": [

                ],
                "table": "`loop`",
                "best_access_path": {
                  "considered_access_paths": [
                    {
                      "access_type": "ref",
                      "index": "idx_loop_prod_timestamps",
                      "chosen": false,
                      "cause": "range_uses_more_keyparts"
                    },
                    {
                      "rows_to_scan": 23325020,
                      "access_type": "range",
                      "range_details": {
                        "used_index": "PRIMARY"
                      },
                      "resulting_rows": 2.33e7,
                      "cost": 4.68e6,
                      "chosen": true
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "condition_filtering_pct": 100,
                "rows_for_plan": 2.33e7,
                "cost_for_plan": 4.68e6,
                "chosen": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "attaching_conditions_to_tables": {
              "original_condition": "((`loop`.`partner_id` = 'VMF') and (`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null))",
              "attached_conditions_computation": [
                {
                  "table": "`loop`",
                  "rechecking_index_usage": {
                    "recheck_reason": "low_limit",
                    "limit": 1000,
                    "row_estimate": 2.33e7
                  }
                }
              ],
              "attached_conditions_summary": [
                {
                  "table": "`loop`",
                  "attached": "((`loop`.`partner_id` = 'VMF') and (`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null))"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "optimizing_distinct_group_by_order_by": {

            }
          },
          {
            "finalizing_table_conditions": [
              {
                "table": "`loop`",
                "original_table_condition": "((`loop`.`partner_id` = 'VMF') and (`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null))",
                "final_table_condition   ": "((`loop`.`partner_id` = 'VMF') and (`loop`.`type_id` in ('PostType-275e2809-5658-48ba-b3cf-0884f5851347','PostType-cb20489a-80ab-411b-93cc-6a9dc3341eba','PostType-e53411b6-ab01-4825-ac47-6d6e18d7a301','PostType-3b79c6ee-1d4b-471a-a23f-4e851016c5a9','PostType-1cdac073-9cfd-4388-98ca-86b140921adb','PostType-4ca8e767-5a57-4cf2-8635-8f3f78b7f9e9')) and ((`loop`.`created` between '2021-02-09 00:00:00' and `loop`.`created`) < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999') and (`loop`.`deleted` is null))"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "refine_plan": [
              {
                "table": "`loop`"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "considering_tmp_tables": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "join_execution": {
        "select#": 1,
        "steps": [

        ]
      }
    }
  ]
},
0,
0
```

Comment: look at the execution plans or explain and yozu will see that mysql 8 uses diffremnt indexes so try a HINT

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Try using MySQL 8's EXPLAIN ANALYZE functionality!

Comment: And provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  And `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'loop';`

Comment: 5.7 ignored `DESC` in an `INDEX` definition.

Comment: Test `CREATE INDEX idx ON loop (partner_id, deleted, created, type_id, post_id)`.

Comment: *A query that looks as follows returns in less than 80ms .. A count of this same query takes over a minute to return* This is about nothing. Test 1st query with `LIMIT 25 OFFSET (result of 2nd query - 25)`...

Comment: Does MySQL accept a syntax like "AND created BETWEEN '2021-02-09 00:00:00' AND created < '2021-08-08 23:59:59.999'" ?

Comment: @RickJames thanks for the reminder as I failed to look at the JSON version of the explain statement. The index being used by the COUNT statement vs that of the actual select statement was very much sub optimal. 

Reviewing a better covering index now and will update the question to reflect what I should have done in the first place.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the Optimizer.  The distribution of the values possibly has some impact.  What is the value of the `COUNT(*)`?  The "Optimizer trace" may provide more insight.